# Python dataframe Convert datetime column into seconds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a datetime columns showing difference in time. I want to convert it into seconds.

My code:

```
df =
index                    timediff
2019-12-02 08:36:02               NaT
2019-12-02 08:36:04   0 days 00:00:02
2019-12-02 08:36:08   0 days 00:00:04
2019-12-02 08:36:10   0 days 00:00:02
2019-12-02 08:36:14   0 days 00:00:04
2019-12-02 15:54:29   0 days 00:00:06
2019-12-02 15:54:31   0 days 00:00:02
2019-12-02 15:54:41   0 days 00:00:10
2019-12-02 15:54:44   0 days 00:00:03
2019-12-02 15:54:50   0 days 00:00:06

df['secs'] = df['timedif'].strftime("%S")
```

present output:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: your column 'timedif' is of dtype timedelta, not datetime. you could use `df['timedif'].dt.total_seconds()`.

Comment: @MrFuppes I thought that it is datetime format only. Didn't think much of it. You are right. Now it worked perfectly as I wanted. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the date-time objects inside the series via `dt`:

```
df['secs'] = df['timedif'].dt.strftime("%S")
```

or if you are using timedelta:

```
df['secs'] = df['timedif'].dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: `import datetime as dt` with this, I ran above code. I got `AttributeError: 'TimedeltaProperties' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Comment: @Mainland: `dt` in this context is not the datetime module... [dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks for correcting this. I even imported the module in that way. Now it is working fine. Thanks a ton. so `dt` is a function. Now I understood that `dt` for working on series or columns. The normal `.strftime("%S")` would work on index only.

Comment: `df['timedif'].dt.strftime("%S")` still throws error as in my above first comment. Looks like only the `df['timedif'].dt.total_seconds()` works here. Any reason?